# Connect MySQL container to docker swarm

Tags: mysql, docker, swarm

I have a swarm with 3 physical hosts. I want to run a cluster of containers that run my Python application. The python program communicates with a Mysql db which is in another container and inserts data into it. I would like to have a single database in one of the hosts and make all the containers to communicate with it.Is there any way I can do that? Should I run the Mysql container inside the swarm or outside? Moreover, should I create a data volume for data persistence? Any help would be really appreciated!